# Add Output of Integers in C++?

Tags: c++

I am working on Project Euler, the first problem, and I've gotten this program to output the numbers I need, but I cannot figure out how to take the outputted numbers and add them together.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void) {

    int test = 0;

    while (test<1000) {
        test++;
            if (test%3 == 0 && test%5 == 0) {

                std::cout << test << std::endl;

            }
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can either store them in a container and use `std::accumulate` or maintain a `total` variable. Seeing as how you're not using the actual numbers later, the latter is better in this situation. Don't forget to initialize it to 0.

Comment: @chris: Might as well make that the answer.

Comment: It says accumulate is not a member of std.

Comment: @JesseGood, I guess. It was meant to be <1 line originally.

Comment: @DustinL., that requires `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding you correctly.  Here's what I wrote to try and implement your suggestion.  http://pastebin.com/fkdPm7uP

Comment: @DustinL., Sometime I would recommend going through the containers and algorithms C++ has to offer and learning how to use them. They're very powerful, and pretty much can all be used with ease after you learn to use one. The problem in this case is that you need something to hold the elements to total before you can total them. It also requires a range; it doesn't assume the whole container.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I will definitely look into them!

Comment: @DustinL., And before you get into the wrong site, as it's so easy to fall into (cplusplus is the top goole hit and has even more wrong with it in this section), use this site as a reference for them: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would be a `total` variable that you add to as the criteria match.

The first step is creating it and initializing it to 0, so you end up with the right number later.

```
int total = 0;
```

After that, subtotals are added to it, so that it accumulates the overall total.

```
total += 5;
...
total += 2;
//the two subtotals result in total being 7; no intermediate printing needed
```

Once you've added on the subtotals, you can just print it as the overall total.

```
std::cout << total;
```

Now, here's how it fits into the code at hand, along with some other pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> //<-- you're not using anything in here, so get rid of it

int main() {
    int test = 0;
    int total = 0; //step 1; don't forget to initialize it to 0

    while (test<1000) { //consider a for loop instead
        test++;

        if (test % 3 == 0 && test % 5 == 0) {
            //std::cout << test << std::endl;
            total += test; //step 2; replace above with this to add subtotals
        }
    }

    std::cout << total << std::endl; //step 3; now we just output the grand total

    std::cin.get();    
    return 0; //this is implicit in c++ if not provided
}
```

Comment: Thank you...for explaining it and not being rude like the user above: "H2CO3"

Comment: Your answer is correct, but with this kind of question, I think it is better to provide guidance to the asker instead of giving him the entire code (see [this MetaSO post about homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/158806)). However, you included many comments that could help Dustin L. learn new things, which is a commendable initiative.

Comment: @LucTouraille, Yes, I know what you're saying. I realize this isn't homework, but that it can be thought of like homework. The truth is that the OP wrote the full code except for that one small missing piece, so the program was ultimately done by them. Showing the code also allowed me to easily point out the comments inlined into my code without turning the post into *code* comment *code* comment.

Comment: I agree with you, Luc.  I certainly wouldn't expect anyone to just write the code for me, which is why I thanked Chris for explaining it to me. :)  I'd much prefer to learn than to have it handed to me.

Comment: @DustinL., I changed the post to focus more on the learning aspect of it, at which point the solution fits in more nicely. Even if you're already done with this, someone else might get more use out of it later.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this is to use another variable to hold the sum. You gradually add each number to this variable until you have to total at the end of your loop.